# Converting string to number of seconds

Tags: javascript, string, date

I'm trying to create a simple program that converts the numbers of hours provided by the user into seconds, and asks the user to reenter hours ,if he provides a string.It works fine when I enter non-positive number, but doesn't show any message if entered a string value.
Here is the code:

```
        function convertToSeconds () {
            var d = prompt("Enter any hour between 0-24","4");
            if ( d<0 ){
                alert("Please enter a number greater than zero");
                convertToSeconds();
            }
            else if( typeof d == String ) {
                /*Problem seems to be here*/
                alert(d + " is not a valid number");
                convertToSeconds();
            }
            else {
            var seconds = 3600*parseFloat(d);
            document.write(seconds);
            }
        };
        convertToSeconds();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an issue with your code. `typeof "any string" = "string"`  not `String`, also JS coerces a number in a string format to a number by default so I would recommend checking for string before number.

```
function convertToSeconds () {
var d = prompt("Enter any hour between 0-24","4");

    if ( d<0 ){
        alert("Please enter a number greater than zero");
        convertToSeconds();
    }        
    else if( isNaN(d) ) {
        /*Problem seems to be here*/
        alert(d + "is not a valid number");
        convertToSeconds();
    }
    else {
    var seconds = 3600*parseFloat(d);
    document.write(seconds);
    }
};
convertToSeconds();
```

Comment: that didn't work..now when the user enters a digit,it still says: 4 is not a valid number

Answer (score 0):

The *prompt* method **only** returns strings. You need to determine if the string can be converted to a positive integer between 0 and 24, so:

```js
var d = prompt('Enter any hour between 0-24');

if ( /^(1?[0-9]|2[0-4])$/.test(d) ) {
  alert('looks good');
} else {
  alert('don\'t like that');
}
```

or you could do something like:

```
var d = Number(prompt('Enter any hour between 0-24'));
if (d == parseInt(d) && d > -1 && d < 25 {
  // ok
}
  // not ok
}
```